# Django: Encapsulate the whole template in the spaceless tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

It would eliminate whitespace. But, other than poor readability, any potential risks I should be aware of?

Here is [the Django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) for the tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The filter will parse the whole output, which might slow down rendering a bit.

Given the reduced readability and potential performance woes, I would refrain from filtering whitespaces.

The question is what you want to achieve by filtering white spaces. If you are concerned about traffic or transfer speed, check if you can use gzip compression. It will probably have a bigger impact.

Comment: Looked further into just using gzip compression with nginx to save space. Think that was the right path. Thank Mr. Hepper.

Answer (score 0):

Worth it? That's a highly-subjective call, but probably not. I always use clean indentation and spacing in the template source file, but I've stopping concerning myself with how nice the output actually looks. Removing excess whitespace *would* make the file size smaller and thus faster to transmit, though, so if that's a concern removing whitespace isn't a bad idea.